# LINQ query to extract all answers that contain any keyword from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IEnumerable<DataModel> data` which has `answers`.  I want to extract all answers that contain any keywords from a list provided. 
For instance,

```
List<string> keywords = new List<string>();
keywords.Add(‘text1’, ‘text2’); 
var records = data.Where(x=> x.answer.contain(keywords.any()));
```

This is what I want to achieve. For instance it should return me a records with answer like ‘blah blah text1 blah blah’ or like ‘blah text2 blah blah’.

Comment: Aside from capitalization issues, your solution doesn't seem to far off. Have you tried it? What is the specific problem you are having?

Comment: .Contains does not accept the list as a parameter. That was more like pseudo code.

Comment: x.answer is a string which maps to varchar in the sql table.

Comment: Try `Where( x => keywords.Any( y => x.answer.Contains(y) ))`

Comment: Aha! That should work.. let me try!! Thank you

Comment: That will work, but it's going to be horribly slow if either `answer` or `keywords` is very long.

Comment: Jim, any other solution do you propose?

Comment: That depends on if you're looking for whole words in `answer`, or if you're just looking for the existence of the string. For example, if you have `the` as a keyword, do you want to find it in "**the**re"? Or do you just want whole words?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
data.All(x => keywords.Any(y => x.answer.Contains(y)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        List<String> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Test");
        list.Add("Test Street");
        list.Add("Street work");
        list.Add("Test machine");


        List<String> products = list;
        var filtered = from String p in products
                       where p.Contains("Test") == true
                       select p;
        // filtered contains the result
        foreach (String product in filtered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(product);
        }

    }
}
```

[dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZsUNS4)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not complete. You are talking about keywords. Do you really mean words, as in sequences of non-whitespace characters surrounded by white spaces? Or dou you just want sequences of characters?

```
[0] This text seems odd.
[1] Oddly enough this text seems normal
```

If you have the word "Odd" in your sequence of keywords, do you want [1](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx) in your result, or do you only want the string with the word "odd" in it?

Do you want [0] to be in your result, in other words, should it be case sensitive?

If a keyword is really a word, then you should first split your string into words. A word is probably a sequence of non-whitespace characters surrounded by at least one whitespace character or the beginning / end of string.

My advice would be to create an extension method for this. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitInWords(this string text)
{
    // TODO: some regular expression that tries to find words
    // search stackoverflow for a method that suits your needs
}
```

Once you've got a function to split the text into words, split your input sequence of text into a sequence of sequences of words. Intersect every sequence of words with your sequence of keyWords. If the intersection is not empty (= if there is anything in the intersection), then keep the sequence in your result.

```
IEnumerable<string> keyWords = ...
IEnumerable<string> inputLines = ...
var linesContainingKeywords = inputLines.SplitIntoWords()
     // result: a sequence of sequences of words
     // keep only those sequence of words that have at least one keyWord in it
     // in other words: that have a non-empty intersection
    .Where(wordSequence => wordSequence.Intersect(keyWords).Any());
```